# Choices from enum in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic (v2.6.1) class with an attribute and I want to limit the possible choices user can make. I can use an enum for that. But the catch is, I have multiple classes which need to enforce different choices. See the example below,

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, field_validator


class FruitEnum(str, Enum):
    pear = 'pear'
    banana = 'banana'
    grapes = 'grapes'


class CookingModel_1(BaseModel):
    fruit: FruitEnum

    @field_validator('fruit')
    def _validate_fruit(cls, value):
      if value not in (FruitEnum.pear,
                       FruitEnum.grapes):
        raise ValueError(f'{value} is not a allowed fruit.!')

class CookingModel_2(BaseModel):
    fruit: FruitEnum

    @field_validator('fruit')
    def _validate_fruit(cls, value):
      if value not in (FruitEnum.banana,
                       FruitEnum.grapes):
        raise ValueError(f'{value} is not a allowed fruit.!')
```

for my `CookingModel_1` and `CookingModel_2` class the choices of `fruit` is different.

I can achieve the task like shown above. But if my list of Cooking models are large (let's say 15 or so), I'll have to define a validator in each class and that's a lot of redundant code doing the same (almost) thing.

Building on that, I can define a nested function to make a parameterized-fieldvalidator like shown below and reduce the redundant code.

```
def get_fruit_validator(allowed_fruits):
  def _validator(fruit):
    if fruit not in allowed_fruits:
      raise ValueError(f'{fruit} is not a allowed fruit.!')
    return fruit
  return _validator


class FruitEnum(str, Enum):
    pear = 'pear'
    banana = 'banana'
    grapes = 'grapes'


class CookingModel_1(BaseModel):
    fruit: FruitEnum

    _fruit_validator = field_validator('fruit')(get_fruit_validator({FruitEnum.pear, FruitEnum.grapes}))

class CookingModel_2(BaseModel):
    fruit: FruitEnum

    _fruit_validator = field_validator('fruit')(get_fruit_validator({FruitEnum.banana, FruitEnum.grapes}))
```

This is good enough for my use case.

But can lead to redundant code if I had multiple fields which expects other enums and long lists. I'm looking for more "elegant" solution. Maybe a new ConstraintType that can help restrict the choices? Do we have any alternative solution for this that doesn't involve writing custom validators?

Comment: Have you considered `Literal['foo', 'bar']`

Comment: ah, that's exactly I wanted. Thank you. I can see that Literal type can solve this. Do you mind adding an answer with your suggestion so that I can accept it? Thank you

Comment: Would have been nice if Field supported choices as well given that is supports integer constraints like lt, gt and even multiple_of :)

Comment: Hmm, why not define more granular enums? That seems like it would make things clearer. (unless this subset stuff is only a one-off occurrence)

Comment: yes, once the subset stuff is decided it is pretty much set in stone and likely never change. Also, splitting in to multiple enums seems tedious and make those enums tightly coupled to the classes. For example, FruitEnumClass_1 is only used by CookingModel_1. FruitEnumClass_1 has no role in the code other than serving CookingModel_1 the overhead of storing the enum and maintaining it is not worth it. But your idea makes sense if the subsets are likely to change more with time

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @yaakov-bressler, I was able to use Literal from typing_extensions to solve this, See the code below

```
from typing_extensions import Literal

class CookingModel_1(BaseModel):
    fruit: Literal[FruitEnum.pear, FruitEnum.grapes]

class CookingModel_2(BaseModel):
    fruit: Literal[FruitEnum.banana, FruitEnum.grapes]
```